# Suddenly pokemon do not show up indoors

Tags: pokemon-go

Suddenly, I realize I don't see any Pokemon poke outside when I am indoors.
Usually if I leave my phone for a while, about 2-3 Pokemon will come out to catch.
But for last 24 hours, not a single Pokemon is showing outside.
The Pokemon only show up when I go out from my house and walk outside.
I can catch few Pokemon outdoors, but as soon as I go indoors (either my house or my office), no Pokemon show up at all.
I am currently level 22, can you help me?

Did I get soft banned or is there an error?  I never cheat or use bots.

Comment: It's just bad luck. Pokemon spawns are random and have nothing to do with your location.

Comment: bad luck happen till 24 hours ?   till now not a single out pokemon poke out in my house,,, but once i go outside i can capture few pokemons as usual

Comment: Are you you connected to WiFi while indoors? I've noticed that if I have WiFi disabled and only use my Data plan, I lose my GPS signal while indoors, and at some point the a game update made *almost everything* not work while your GPS signal is weak/lost.

Comment: yes, i use both WI FI and my phone network at home.   i even try disable WIFI only use data plan,   and vice versa... but neither work.  while indoors, i still can access pokestops (  one of the pokestop just next to my house), but no pokemon poke out at all..  very weird,   have submit to niantic as well but no response yet

Comment: Hmm, sorry, that was the only thing I could figure was happening.

Comment: You said that you were leaving your phone to pick it up later. Maybe Niantic just made sure that the pokemons despawns on their timer instead of waiting the next screen update. Maybe the spawning spots for pokemons have been moved in your area. Kinda hard to help you because on my side everything is fine in that regard.

Answer (score 2):

Like 1 and half day ago, there was a huge migration of nests and spawn points (see e.g. [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/TheSilphRoad/comments/5b7m88/new_spawn_points_added/)). In cases of all other migrations, some spawns were added, some removed, but in this case, it feels like **all** spawns were changes.

So the most likely explanation is that prior the migration you had some spawn points in your home and office, while now there are not. Pure coincidence.

For general details how spawn points work, you may check [this guide](http://pokemongohub.net/pokemon-go-spawn-points-guide/).

Also there are some reports about nearby getting emptied after staying on the same place for a longer time. So if your nearby list suddenly disappears, try restarting the app.

Comment: Thanks for your input Eulali camir,  just feel weird as i saw a lot of sightings in my house (4-5 pokemon, sometime even 6-7) but none of them ever spawn out.   but if i walk out my house less than 50 m, soon 1 or 2 will spawn out.   i wasting my whole afternoon and evening testing this  and make me feel more weird and desperate... :(...